# How to get all counts of likes of post of our page? #LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

**How to get all counts of likes of post of our page**, Actually we have created a Page and posted some articles. Now I want to retrieve all likes of my post using APIs, I can get the access token from Postman.
When i am run the V2 API to get data thru poastman, i got the following error:
"**Not enough permissions to access: GET /socialActions/**".
Please advise what more permission required.

Get the Access Token from postman for OAuth2.0 under Auth navigation of postman. After getting the access token, run the https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{activity}
I am getting following error
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 65604,
    "message": "Empty oauth2 access token",
    "status": 401
}

I used in other system Postman then found following error:
{
    "serviceErrorCode": ,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /socialActions/",
    "status": 401
}

Should be come the result data in JSON format

Comment: How are you passing the Access Token for the Activity API?

Comment: Here steps are defined https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-started
Through Postman, got the Access Token

Comment: @Shail have you found a solution? Got the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406550/getting-linkedin-company-shares-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this request https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics#sample-request

Following is sample request

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:xxxxxx&shares=urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxx&count=1000
```

Sample Response :

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "totalShareStatistics": {
                "shareCount": 2,
                "clickCount": 1,
                "engagement": 10,
                "likeCount": 5,
                "impressionCount": 7,
                "commentCount": 5
            },
            "share": "urn:li:share:xxxxxx",
            "organizationalEntity": "urn:li:organization:xxxxx"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "count": 1000,
        "start": 0,
        "links": []
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting following error:
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-organizationalEntity /organizationalEntityShareStatistics",
    "status": 403
}
Please suggest!

Comment: Your app should have access to "r_organization_social"

Comment: @kaushik  have the same issue and ```r_organization_social```` is in my app's scope. I included it in the scope when getting an access token. Have you tested above? LinkedIn's docus are not great...